# insert value of one col to another on inserting

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert, default-value, constraints

i want to insert value of one col to another on inserting new row in sql.

how do i? there is any way to do this by default value(constraint)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a trigger to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not aware from triggers, can you explain for me by one example?

Comment: I googled T-SQL + Triggers and got this http://www.devguru.com/technologies/t-sql/7138.asp